# Dynamically cascade type in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, cascade

I am using JPA in my application, and take one model for example:

```
public class Project {
    @Id
    private String uuid;
    private String name;

    .................

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ProjectDetails> details;
}
```

As shown,there is a `one-to-many` association between the `Project` and the `ProjectDetail`, once a project is fetched, its details will be populated by the jpa provider which is exactly what I want.

However once the authentication is added to the project, the details will be only available for specified users, which means the auto-fetching `details` is not necessary.

I know I can use the

```
project.setDetails(null);
```

to remove the `details` information for un-authenticated user in the application level. But I wonder if this is a waste of sql resource? So it would be better if I can set the cascade type at runtime.

How do you solve this kind of problem?

Comment: Cascade will control whether changes to the master entity will get propagated to the associated entity (if a new associated entity will get committed when committing the parent, if changes to the associated entity will get propagated when merging the parent etc).

Comment: OneToMany should be loaded lazily, which means that it will only be loaded when calling the getter. Maybe you could wrap the getter with another method and only call the getter if authentication allows that, otherwise return null instead.

Answer (score 0):

By default, since @OneToMany relationships are lazily loaded, you may not necessarily access the getter from your code if the user has not yet been authenticated thereby preventing the relationship from been loaded.

When the entity eventually gets loaded, I think you should just decide on what to do from your application rather than setting the relationship to null.